# How can I call fragment class in activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

s2.java..

```
public class S2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener,OnTouchListener

 {
...

 @Override

public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        ....
           //I want to call s1.java class here

   }


}
```

s1.java

```
public class S1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener
{

...
}
```

now I want to call s1.java which extends fragment in s2.java onbackpress().

Comment: S2 should extend FragmentActivity instead of Activity

Comment: But according to my requirement it should be an activity

Comment: @pinky and what is the requirement?

Comment: that activity is for zoom

Comment: I believe that you can use FragmentActivity instead of Activity,that should not break your requirement.

Comment: In any case, since he didnt mention he need to support older versions, FragmentActivity is not required to use fragments... You can use classic Activity class if you support android 3.0 and higher...

Comment: I changed to fragmentactivity now can i pass fragment to intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
s2.java..

public class S2 extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener,OnTouchListener

{ ...

@Override

public void onBackPressed() { .... //I want to call s1.java class here
   S1 fragmentS1 = new S1();
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();
}

}

s1.java

public class S1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

... }
```

Comment: what exactly this line does                                                                   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();
}

Comment: in my fragment class I dnt have any fragment. can you plz xplain what that getfragmentmanager does

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access instance of your fragment object you can do it like this:

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
```

You can set TAG for certain fragment, when you are adding it to your activity, like this:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
```